# How do you enable the Borderlands 2 console on the Mac?

Tags: borderlands-2, macos

My searching has found lots of sites that show you how to enable the Borderlands 2 console on the PC, but I am on Mac, and I want to open the console so I can see what my FPS are looking like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only real trick is finding the files. On my Mac they're in:

```
 ~/Library/Application Support/Borderlands 2/WillowGame/Config
```

I did find one online reference that talked about editing `DefaultInput.ini`. I don't have that file, but making the corresponding edit in `WillowInput.ini` did enable the console.

Answer (score 3):

For the Steam version of Borderlands 2 for Mac I found the "BaseInput.ini" file located at:

> ~/Library/Application Support/Steam/SteamApps/common/Borderlands 2/Borderlands2.app/Contents/GameData/Engine/Config/BaseInput.ini

Once you find the Borderlands 2 Application you will need to right click on it and click "Show Package Contents" to find the Contents folder. Open the BaseInput.ini file and locate the line:

> [Engine.Console]

Add or modify the lines first two lines below the [Engine.Console] line so they look like this:

> ConsoleKey=Tilde
>   TypeKey=Backslash

Here is what lines 224-228 look like in my BaseInput.ini file:

> [Engine.Console]
>   ConsoleKey=Tilde
>   TypeKey=Backslash
>   MaxScrollbackSize=1024
>   HistoryBot=-1

Save the BaseInput.ini file and launch Borderlands 2. Now the ~ key will open the console and the \ key will open a single line console that is useful for taking screenshots. For more information and commands go to this URL:

http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=148783